# Why does my css shift the textbox downwards and to the next line?

Tags: layout, css

I've been banging my head for hours trying to figure this out. Why, in [this demo](http://jsbin.com/eciyib/5/), is the textbox shifted downwards a bit and not on the same line as the blue box? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Sorry if I didn't state this clearly: **The top of the text box should align with the top of the blue box.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: About the seemingly "wrong" vertical placement.

You have to apply `margin-top:6px;margin-bottom:0px;` to the span to fix the issue (**See http://jsbin.com/eciyib/8**). By default, the top and bottom margin of the `span` is 10px, as defined by the `#toolbar > *` selector. The `<input>` element has a top and bottom margin of just 6px, as specified at the `#url` selector.

---

You haven't defined a `width` property for the `div#toolbar` element. See below. When the viewport is smaller than `1690px`, the input element will shift down, to fit.

**JSBin: http://jsbin.com/eciyib/7/**

```
div#toolbar   <missing width property>
    span      margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 5px; width: 22px;    total=  37px
    input#url margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 10px; width: 1228px;
              border-left-widt: 5px; border-right-width:5px         total=1553px
                                                                    total=1690px
```

Further explained:

- The elements have a margin-left and right of 5px, due  `#toolbar > * {margin:10px 5px;}`
- The `#toolbar > *:first-child` and `#toolbar > *:last-child` selectors change the left and right margin of the childs to 10px.
- As a result, both elements have a **horizontal margin of 15px**
- The input element has a fixed width of `1228px`, as defined inline
- The input element inherit a left and right border of 5px, from the browser.

Comment: Read my reply to Vilx. Changing the width of the textbox isn't fixing it.

Comment: @Abraham You have probably applied the wrong widths. It's fixed for me: http://jsbin.com/eciyib/7/ I have explained the composition of the width very thoroughly. Hope you understand it.

Comment: It still doesn't work. The top of the textbox is below the top of the blue box, and the bottom of the textbox spills out of the `div`.

Comment: You have to add `margin-bottom: 0px;margin-top:6px;` to the span to fix your issue.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Adding `margin-bottom: 0` fixed it. Thanks for your help and patience!

Comment: BTW, why did you say the textbox had a 5px border? Textboxes have a 1px border.

Comment: @Abraham You haven't declared a width, so it's dependent on the browser. In Firefox 7.0.1, the left and right border of a textbox is 5px by default.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that there is a bit of Javascript there that makes sure that the textbox is always as wide as the viewport (or close to it). After that, it's simple line-wrapping that makes sure that the textbox is in the next line.

Comment: Vilx and Smamatti: I don't think that's the problem, because if I load the page, then use Chrome's dev tools to shrink the width of the textbox, it's still incorrectly positioned.

Comment: I removed the line which resizes the textbox, and it stayed in the same line. The problem is that the `window.onresize` also triggers when the textbox is resized, so your efforts with Chrome's tools are immediately reversed.

Comment: You mean the line `$url.width($window.width() - toolbarWidth)`? I removed it and it didn't seem to fix it.

Comment: Hold on a minute, I've been using Chrome. Let me see if it's an issue with Chrome.

Comment: It works now. Adding `margin-bottom:0` as per Rob fixed it. Thanks for your help and patience! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your input is too wide to fit into the same line and the margin in one rule is positioning it this way:

```
#toolbar > * {
    margin: 10px 5px;
}
```